# What is the definition of $L^p(0,T; L^p_{loc}(R^n)), p\ge 1$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces

I saw the space $L^p(0,T; L^p_{loc}(\mathbb R^n))$  in a paper about parabolic equation. But I only know
$$
L^p_{loc}(\mathbb R^n) =\{
u:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R: u\in L^p(V),  \forall ~ V\subset \subset  \mathbb R^n
\}
$$
But I don't know what is $L^p(0,T; L^p_{loc}(\mathbb R^n))$ , and what is its norm.

Besides, I want a book can be used to find the notation of parabolic equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are Bochner Spaces. Basically functions $f(t,\cdot)$  which are in $L^p_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ independent of time parameter $t \in [0,T]$. The norm of $L^p([0,T],L^p(\mathbb{R}^n))$ is $$\|f\|^p_{L^p([0,T],L^p(\mathbb{R}^n))}:=\int_0^T ||f(t,\cdot)||^p_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}dt$$.

Some references

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_space.
- *H.Brezis, Functional Analysis,Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations, Chapter 10.*
- Any book about time evolving, Parabolic, or Hyperbolic PDE.